# How to resloved -below errors

Tags: java, jmeter, taurus

I pass config yml file as -->

```
execution:
- executor: selenium
  iterations: 1
  scenario: sel

scenarios:
  sel:
    script: F:\Taurus\Orange\OrangeHRM_File\AEDDE\LoginPage_OrangeHRM.java
    additional-classpath: F:\Taurus\junit-4.13.1.jar
services:
 - module: proxy2jmx
modules:
 blazemeter:
  token: 707ab1011445rrtrtrt13827f:7e30d7ba25e39c53f1e1cf4ggg98975645gd97fb567139f
```

got error-->
SEVERE: Failed to process class:

```
sers\sam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.22.0.20211202-1200\org\eclipse\epp\common\ContributeHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sers\sam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.22.0.20211202-1200\org\eclipse\epp\common\ContributeHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
```

&

```
SEVERE: Failed to process class: sers\sam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.18.1.20211011-2139\org\apache\maven\index\NexusArchetypeDataSource
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sers\sam\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.18.1.20211011-2139\org\apache\maven\index\NexusArchetypeDataSource
```

&

```
SEVERE: Failed to process class: org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.Slf4jLog
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
```

&

```
SEVERE: Failed to process class: META-INF.versions.9.org.junit.platform.commons.util.ModuleUtils$ModuleReferenceScanner
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: META-INF/versions/9/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ModuleUtils$ModuleReferenceScanner has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

So how is it resolved?

Comment: it would seem not everything you are trying to use is on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specify **all the dependencies** you're using via [`additional-classpath` entries](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/#Scenario-Examples)
2. You need to upgrade your Java to [OpenJDK 9](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) (or later) as one of your libraries is built with JDK 9 and you won't be able to use it with Java 8
3. There is no need to use Taurus, you can just configure your WebDriver instance to use a [proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#proxy) and specify [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) as the proxy server, this way you will also get [automatic correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80/).